# What does "selecting 'python-clang-3.8' for regex 'clang-3.8'" mean?

Tags: debian, installation, apt-get, clang, iot

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi 3. The device uses Raspbian, which is Debian derivative. I'm trying to install Clang 3.8 because Clang 3.7 appears to [lack proper sanitizer support](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=779785).

When I run the install command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install clang-3.8
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python-clang-3.8' for regex 'clang-3.8'
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

$ clang-3.8
-bash: clang-3.8: command not found
$ clang
-bash: clang: command not found

$ find /usr/bin -name '*clang*'
$
```

What does *"selecting 'python-clang-3.8' for regex 'clang-3.8'"* mean?

What, exactly, is the regex being referred to?

Where is Clang after the install?

Comment: As far as I can see Raspbian doesn't have clang 3.8 in the default repositories (http://www.raspberryconnect.com/raspbian-packages-list/item/58-raspbian-devel#c). Did you add other repositories? I don't really understand the 'selecting...' line either since python-clang-3.8 doesn't seem to exist either.